# Mongo Change Stream "not authorized to execute command"

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, changestream

Here is the problem.
I have local `mongos` instance that is connected to remote `mongod`.
Remote DB uses basic password authentication. 
I'm trying to setup ChangeStream watcher for particular collection with simple Scala application.
The actual code looks like that:

```scala
  private val mongo = new MongoClient(
    new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017),
    MongoCredential.createCredential("username", "myDB", "password".toCharArray),
    MongoClientOptions.builder().addServerListener(ServerStateListener).build()
  )
  private val collection = mongo
    .getDatabase(DB)
    .getCollection("someObjectsCollection")

  private val ch = collection
    .watch()
    .fullDocument(FullDocument.UPDATE_LOOKUP)
    .iterator()
```

It breaks on `.fullDocument(FullDocument.UPDATE_LOOKUP)` line telling:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 13: 'not authorized on myDB to execute command { aggregate: "someObjectsCollection", pipeline: [ { $changeStream: { fullDocument: "updateLookup" } } ], cursor: {}, $db: "myDB", $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1524064297, 2), ....
```

That's confusing because given user credentials working through `mongo shell` both on remote DB and local `mongos`. Moreover, I tried to perform some other actions with collection inside that application (like `collection.count()`) and it works! The problem appears when I'm trying to setup the watcher.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

finally I figured out what was wrong with my setup...

original user 'username' that I was using to consume change stream had strict permission set:

```
"inheritedPrivileges" : [
    {
        "resource" : {
            "db" : "abuCoreDev", 
            "collection" : ""
        }, 
        "actions" : [
            "convertToCapped", 
            "createCollection", 
            "createIndex", 
            "dropIndex", 
            "find", 
            "insert", 
            "listCollections", 
            "listIndexes", 
            "planCacheIndexFilter", 
            "remove", 
            "update"
        ]
    }
],
```

I didn't realize that I need special `changeStream` permission to consume change streams! Everything works fine when I connect to `mongos` as `root` which has that cursed permission.

Here you can see permissions for my root user:

```
{
            "resource" : {
                "db" : "", 
                "collection" : ""
            }, 
            "actions" : [
                "bypassDocumentValidation", 
                "changeCustomData", 
                "changePassword", 
                "changeStream", 
                "collMod", 
                "collStats", 
                "compact", 
                "convertToCapped", 
                "createCollection", 
                "createIndex", 
                "createRole", 
                "createUser", 
                "dbHash", 
                "dbStats", 
                "dropCollection", 
                "dropDatabase", 
                "dropIndex", 
                "dropRole", 
                "dropUser", 
                "emptycapped", 
                "enableProfiler", 
                "enableSharding", 
                "find", 
                "getShardVersion", 
                "grantRole", 
                "indexStats", 
                "insert", 
                "killCursors", 
                "listCollections", 
                "listIndexes", 
                "moveChunk", 
                "planCacheIndexFilter", 
                "planCacheRead", 
                "planCacheWrite", 
                "reIndex", 
                "remove", 
                "renameCollectionSameDB", 
                "repairDatabase", 
                "revokeRole", 
                "setAuthenticationRestriction", 
                "splitChunk", 
                "splitVector", 
                "storageDetails", 
                "update", 
                "validate", 
                "viewRole", 
                "viewUser"
            ]
        }
```